# retrieve dependencies from multiple enterprise repositories

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml

There are two repositories in our company(say A,B). Our team uses repo A. I need to get a dependency from repo B for my Java build.
I tried the following.

1. Added an additional mirror in maven settings file for the repo B. I have set repo A as a mirror for 'one' and repo B as a mirror for 'two' . Previously repo A was the mirror for *.
2. Added the repo B in my pom.xml in repositories .

Dependency is not being pulled.
How to give the username and password for the second repo B in command line just in case necessary because I already give repo A username and password in command line for build.

Answer (score 2):

You can add repo B as "repository" (not mirror), and then change your original mirror to `*,!B`  to exclude B.

I would not define two mirrors, the second one will not properly work.

Another possibility is to add repo B as remote repository in your repo A. Then the problem is solved without changing the `settings.xml`.